# Multiple data-dialog issue for accessing the same popup

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to open a same popup by two different links and I have integrated a very cool popup on my page from this website http://tympanus.net/Development/DialogEffects It's works fine when I use data-dialog="sign-up" only one time on a hyperlink. But when I use it twice as following example then popup doesn't show up.

```
<a href="#" data-dialog="signup">WATCH DEMO</a>
<a href="#" data-dialog="signup">FREE TRIAL</a>
```

Please guide me how can I open the same popup by multiple hyper links.

Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' ),
    signup = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
    dlg = new DialogFx( signup );
    dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
    })();

<div id="signup" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content signup_popup">
         <p>content goes here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to register the function twice as such:

```
$('[data-dialog-overlay]').each(function() 
{
    var dlgtrigger = this;
    somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog-overlay' ) ); 
    dlg = new DialogFx(somedialog); 

    dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
});
```